# showClear Jquery datetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this code to pop up a calendar datetimepicker, I need to be able to clear this field and I am unable to clear it unless I break the Calendar function

```
$('#date_returned').datetimepicker(
{

    showButtonPanel: true,
    showClear: true,
    forceParse: false,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    pickDate: true,
    pickSeconds: false,
    pick12HourFormat: false            
}
```

No matter what I change or add to this it either breaks the ability to Use the Calendar or it breaks the ability for me to clear the field. How can I modify this to allow me to use the added Clear buttton of Bootstrap 3.0 and allow me to use the calender

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code ....

$("#date_returned").datepicker({
     showButtonPanel: true,
     closeText: 'Clear',
     onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
         if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
             document.getElementById(this.id).value = '';
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect. Do I need to tell the php/html on the form page to draw a button for the clear, or does the boostra-dtp have a builtin clear button that I can turn on?

Comment: $('#date_returned').datepicker().datepicker('setDate',new Date());

Answer (score 0):

Don't use input type='reset', make a button called clear, then in jquery do the following

```
$("#clear").click(function(){

    $("#date_returned").val("");

  });
```

Comment: So I need to add another button on the php/html page and then have it linked to this?

Comment: It's one method yes. It's how we do it at my work. Instead of clear form / reset button just add the resets to inside this function, having THIS button clear out all input values, reset select boxes to index 0 etc